# Which electrical signal is better for industry among the following? Why?

Tags: voltage, current

Which electrical signal is better for industry among the following? Why?

1. 0 to 10 volts signal.
2. 0 to 20 milliamps signal.
3. 4 to 20 millimeters signal.

Comment: ...... or digital

Comment: The choice between these signals depends on the specific needs of the industrial application. For example, if you need precision control and are not concerned about signal interference, 0-10 V might be a good choice. If noise and fault detection are concerns, 4-20 mA could be more suitable. It's also worth considering industry standards and the compatibility of existing equipment and components.

Comment: @liaifat85 - Hi, That is an *answer*, not a comment and answering is not an allowed use of comments. Please see [here](/help/privileges/comment) & [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756) for (the deliberately short list of) what is allowed in a comment. Consider writing this into an answer, as the comments here may be deleted.

Comment: Ahs392 - Hi, This looks like coursework / homework. For such questions we *especially* want to see and help with your own thoughts and see your best attempt at an answer. Please [edit] your question to add your own thoughts - what do you think is the answer, and why? Also, why are the units in choice number 3 shown as "millimeters"? Does that make sense? (You listed the same options when you asked this question at [All About Circuits forum](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/196594/) but perhaps no-one noticed there yet.) || As you are new here, please see the [tour] & [help] - thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework without own attempt.

Comment: "better for industry" - *which* industry? There are many different industries, and different industries have different requirments.

Comment: what's a `4 to 20 millimeters signal`?

Answer (score 3):

Among the three, only a 4 - 20 mA signal is failsafe since '0 mA' signals a wire break.

Comment: the other two can also have a `fault state`

Comment: With a 0 - 10 V signal, a wire break will signal '0 V' even when the actual value is greater than 0V. Likewise with a 0 - 20 mA signal. However, with the lower limit being 4 mA for a 4 - 20 mA signal, '0 mA' confirms a signal fault.